# When using OpenCV HoughCirlces I can't access the number of circles detected

Tags: python, opencv, runtime-error, hough-transform

I have been using HoughCircles on a .png image in python. when I run the code:

```
def circleCheck(self, imPath):
    image = cv2.imread(imPath)
    image = cv2.medianBlur(image, 5)
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    circles = cv2.HoughCircles(gray, cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT, 1.2, 100)
    self.alphaCount = len(circles)
```

where alphaCount should contain the number of circles in the image, I get
        `TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()`
I'm not sure why as circles should return a list which has a length, even if that length is 0. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you show your image?

Comment: sample code: circles = cv2.HoughCircles(img,cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT,1,20,
                            param1=50,param2=30,minRadius=0,maxRadius=0)

circles = np.uint16(np.around(circles))
for i in circles[0,:]:
    # draw the outer circle
    cv2.circle(cimg,(i[0],i[1]),i[2],(0,255,0),2)
    # draw the center of the circle
    cv2.circle(cimg,(i[0],i[1]),2,(0,0,255),3)
taken from http://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.org/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_houghcircles/py_houghcircles.html

Comment: I don't need to draw the circles just count how many are there

Comment: Also I am not of high enough reputation to show the image, it is black and white with pixelated dots all over it (the image from a particle detector)